# How do I convert a character into binary?

Tags: java, binary, char

How would you convert a given character in a string to a its corresponding binary value?

```
public void send(DataFrame frame) {
    String bitString = frame.toString();
        for (int a = 0; a < bitString.length(); a++) {
            char c = bitString.charAt(a);
            ????
    }
}
```

where frame is defined to be a byte array (as byte [] in the DataFrame class

Comment: use getBytes() method.

Comment: Is it just me or the question is really about converting a `char` to `binary` and not `byte[]`.

Comment: @R.J exactly right, do you have any idea how I'd go about doing this?

Comment: How can you convert a char to binary? The only way I could think of is, getting the ASCII code(which is an int) and convert that to binary. Is that what you require?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(0x100 + bytes[i]).substring(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        String bitString = frame.toString();
            for (int a = 0; a < bitString.length(); a++) {
                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                b = bitString.getBytes();
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
        }
```